# ffmpeg how do i know what audio rate to use?

Tags: ffmpeg

Say I have something like this

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv 


-ar  (Audio sampling rate in Hz)
-ab  (Audio bit rate in kbit/s)
```

regarding the `-ar` and the `-ab` how do I know what rate to use? I got this ffmpeg command from a site somewhere and I was wondering how the person knew what values to put for the rates? Do I need to understand audio in order to figure that out?

Comment: You should at least understand what a sample rate is and how you check what sample rate has your input file. :)

Comment: The short answer is that yes, you will need to understand some basic things about digital audio encoding in order to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 9):

Probably 44100 for audio sampling rate and 128 for bit rate should be sufficient.

Check [Wikipedia's sampling rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_rate) and [audio bit rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate#Audio_.28MP3.29) articles for examples to see if those values are too high or too low for what you're trying to do.

Comment: You probably mean 44100 instead of 41000?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use "ffmpeg -i video.avi" to know the sampling rate and the bitrate of the audio stream in the source video.avi.

The audio stream can be extracted with the same sampling rate and bitrate without lose quality.

You can decide to reduce one of them for size reasons, but don't increment one of them to increase quality because you never can't upgrade the original quality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using -ar 22050 and -ab 48 for Avi and Mpeg video files. It works normally.